# Does tax influence the effect of greed on resources?

Tags: burning-wheel, dwarf

If the Greed of a Dwarf is higher than his Resources, then the Dwarf gets +1 Ob to Resources tests. If Greed is lower, he may FoRK his Greed into Resources instead.

Tax reduces the Resources exponent. Does tax affect the penalty or FoRK mentioned in the first paragraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the taxed Resources when determining the disadvantage from Greed or ability to FoRK. Tax reduces Resources for everything except advancement; only the advancement rules reference the untaxed Resources exponent.

> If Greed is higher than Resources, the Dwarf is hard put to part with what he has.

Tax is exactly the kind of desperation that drives a Dwarf to use the special Greed rules to be greedy!